# Retain Selection When Click Outside Widget

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-selector

I have a gridview that I'm using to create a calendar.  I am having trouble keeping the initial selection highlighted when I click outside the calendar/gridview.  The calendar/gridview occupies the upper half of the view and is in a fragment and a corresponding list will go below.  My layout for the grid in the fragment is as follows:

```
  <GridView
     android:id="@+id/weekGrid"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:listSelector="@color/green"
     android:numColumns="7" >
  </GridView>
```

To highlight an initial cell, I set its position by using the following after setting the adapter:

```
  calGrid.requestFocusFromTouch();
  calGrid.setSelection(startPosition);
```

The initial selection is green as desired.  However, as soon as I click away from gridview the green background disappears.  This does not happen if I am to select another cell and then click away from the gridview.  In this case the highlighting remains.  I have tried setting a onFocusChange listener on the gridview.  But this is not being triggered when clicking outside the gridview.  I have also tried using a selector in the android:listSelector.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Replace:

```
calGrid.requestFocusFromTouch();
calGrid.setSelection(startPosition);
```

with:

```
((ImageView)calGrid.getChildAt(startPosition)).setSelected(true);
```

I think it should solve your problem, if you aren't using an ImageView, change the cast to the kind of view you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  While I am using a TextView via the adapter setup:

Comment: Sorry.  My adapter takes a layout which is just a TextView and the textview id.  When I use the command above with a (TextView) I get a class cast exception telling me the item returned is a String.  I have tried using the calGrid.getChildAt(startPosition).setSelected(true), but also with no luck.

Comment: Ok, might have messed up a bit but can you please edit your question with your adapter code and your textview layouts?

Comment: I edited my answer, i gave you the wrong method by accident, try it now.

Comment: I had used that earlier.  It works, but as soon as I click outside the gridview, the highlighting is removed.  I ended up setting and removing backgrounds for each cell using the viewtreeobserver to start and then onClick listener for every other selection.